# Data parsing in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have data like

```
state:us,gallery:45,fin:UN,mode:normal,rate:3346
```

as string data type in one of the hive table. I want to extract data like

```
state gallery fin mode    rate
------------------------------
us    45      UN  normal  3346
```

as rows to target table.how can i do this using hive

Need a general approach for instead of comma sometimes # may come
Thats 
state?us#gallery?45#fin?UN#mode?normal#rate?3346

Comment: The required result is unclear

Comment: Sorry i need us,45,UN,normal,3346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t as (select 'state:us,gallery:45,fin:UN,mode:normal,rate:3346' as mycol)

select  mycol_map['state']      as state
       ,mycol_map['gallery']    as gallery
       ,mycol_map['fin']        as fin
       ,mycol_map['mode']       as mode
       ,mycol_map['rate']       as rate

from   (select  str_to_map(mycol) as mycol_map
        from    t
        ) t
```

---

```
+-------+---------+-----+--------+------+
| state | gallery | fin |  mode  | rate |
+-------+---------+-----+--------+------+
| us    |      45 | UN  | normal | 3346 |
+-------+---------+-----+--------+------+
```

Comment: Need state,gallery etc as columns and correspoding data as i mentioned. Sometimes instead of comma thise are swperated by #

Comment: @BigD, still not clear. Take your time and post a good data sample which includes multiple rows. Format the text using ctrl+k

Comment: P.s. You can use sites as https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/ to format your text as a table. Use a tab delimited text.

Comment: Thank you @Dudu. I have edited my questions .i was asking will your solution work if i have data like as mentioned in my questions last part?

Comment: Yes, you can use other delimiters than than the defaults and it will work. Read about `str_to_map`. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: Geeting NULLS @Dudu             hive>        with t as (select 'state=us&gallery=45&fin=UN&mode=normal&rate=3346' as mycol)
    >
    > select  mycol_map['state']      as state
    >        ,mycol_map['gallery']    as gallery
    >        ,mycol_map['fin']        as fin
    >        ,mycol_map['mode']       as mode
    >        ,mycol_map['rate']       as rate
    >
    > from   (select  str_to_map(mycol) as mycol_map
    >         from    t
    >         ) t;
OK
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Time taken: 0.34 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

Comment: Off course you are. You haven't declared the relevant delimiters.Please check `str_to_map` in the link I gave you.

Comment: still getting error     hive> with t as (select 'state=us&gallery=45&fin=UN&mode=normal&rate=3346' as mycol) > > select mycol_map['state'] as state > ,mycol_map['gallery'] as gallery > ,mycol_map['fin'] as fin > ,mycol_map['mode'] as mode > ,mycol_map['rate'] as rate > > from (select str_to_map(mycol,[=,&]) as mycol_map > from t > ) t;

Comment: `select str_to_map ('state=us&gallery=45&fin=UN&mode=normal&rate=3346','&','=')`

Comment: tried this also ..getting NULLS   hive> with t as (select 'state=us&gallery=45&fin=UN&mode=normal&rate=3346' as mycol) > > select mycol_map['state'] as state > ,mycol_map['gallery'] as gallery > ,mycol_map['fin'] as fin > ,mycol_map['mode'] as mode > ,mycol_map['rate'] as rate > > from (select str_to_map(mycol,"=","&") as mycol_map > from t > ) t;

Comment: This is not the correct order of the delimiters. it should be `str_to_map ('...','&','=')`  as I just showed you.